# Why does this code grow so large in memory?

Tags: performance, haskell

if I call `crash` with any value for `increment` and 50000000 (fifty million) for spins, it ramps up and keeps growing in memory size until has choked every last bit of memory and then crashes.

```
crash :: Int -> Int -> Int 
crash increment spins = snd $ foldl' spin' (0,0) [1..spins]
  where spin' = spin increment

spin increment (index,element1) spinNumber = (next,nextElementOne)
  where
    next 
      | indexNIncrement >= spinNumber = 1 + (indexNIncrement `rem` spinNumber)
      | otherwise = 1 + indexNIncrement
    indexNIncrement = index + increment
    nextElementOne
      | next==1 = spinNumber
      | otherwise = element1
```

I don't see how memory is leaked. Doesn't each call to `spin` replace the accumulator value? Doesn't it get released?

Comment: Looks as a strictness issue. Try `spin increment (!index, !element1) spinNumber = ...` with `BangPatterns` on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, at each step `foldl'` will evaluate the result of the function `spin'` at every step, bringing it to WHNF (weak head normal form). Concretely, this means that the result will be evaluated until the first constructor.

However, the result of `spin'` is `(next,nextElementOne)`, which is already in WHNF, since it starts with a pair constructor. What we want is to force the evaluation of the pair components here. One basic solution is to return

```
spin ... = next `seq` (nextElementOne `seq` (next, nextElementOne))
```

so that the components will be evaluated before returning the pair.

A more modern approach could be exploiting `BangPatterns`, instead.